# Como acessar vetores de uma classe em C++

Tags: array, c++, classes

**Eu tenho familiaridade com a linguagem C pura pois desenvolvo sistemas embarcados e microcontroladores. Estou me dedicando muito nos estudos de um novo paradigma de programação que é a orientação a objetos (OOP). Eu me envolvi num projeto pessoal, faz alguns dias, de começar um pequeno desenvolvimento chamado de ‘algoritmo genético’. Está ainda somente num esboço de como criar uma “população” (uma grande string) e separar em "cromossomos" (“pedaços dessa string” ou substrings para cada "indivíduo").

Até aí , tudo certo. O programa funciona quando eu separo em partes. Mas agora eu quero chamar uma variável-membro de uma função que eu criei. Quando eu compilo, ela não aparece embora a compilação não mostre qualquer falha. Já tentei criar outra forma de instanciar a variável numa classe. Gostaria de saber se há alguém com boa experiência em OOP para analisar esse problema e sugerir novas revisões. Agradeço já as manifestações.
**
Observem a linha 187:  [cpp.sh/45jda](http://cpp.sh/45jda)

Comment: A partir do C++11 vc pode iterar pelos elementos de um container STL com um `for (auto& item : lista_itens) { }`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Poderia explicar mais algo sobre essas coisas que não entendi?

> O programa funciona quando eu separo em partes

E como seria essa separação? pode postar um código desses?

> Mas agora eu quero chamar uma variável-membro de uma função que eu criei

Que significa *"chamar variável membro de uma função?"* Classes tem membros. Funções tem um nome, argumentos e um tipo de retorno. E pertencem em geral a uma classe. Podia ter dito de qual variável e qual função está falando.

> Quando eu compilo, ela não aparece embora a compilação não mostre qualquer falha

Que significa? Variáveis não aparecem na compilação.

> Já tentei criar outra forma de instanciar a variável numa classe

E que forma seria essa?

### Sobre seu programa

```
        TransformStrsToDec* acess11;
        acess11 = new TransformStrsToDec;
        acess11->TransformStrsToDec::strnbinars();
```

Essa construção sugere que `strnbinars()` é como um construtor da classe `TransformStrsToDec`.

E o nome da classe sugere que ela transforma `Strs` to `Dec`. Lendo o código parece que os `Str` estão em um vetor de `string` `storageRangeStr` e os `Dec` estão em `dec_storageRangeStr`, um vetor de `long int`.

Se é esse o caso, talvez uma implementação mais simples e descritiva da classe fosse
algo assim

```
class Trf
{
private:
    vector <string>     Str;
    vector <long int>   Dec;

public:
    long int sum;
    long int N, n;
    std::string rangeStr;
    std::string strc0;

public:
    long int strnbinars(void) {};
    Trf(int n, int N) : n(n) , N(N) {};
    Trf() : n(6), N(1800) {};

protected:
    int k, j, index1, r, index2;
};
```

Veja esse trecho com a declaração original e um exemplo usando `Trf`

```
TransformStrsToDec* acess;
acess = new TransformStrsToDec;

Trf* access = new Trf();
Trf* outro = new Trf(12, 3600);
```

Compare. `Trf` tem dois construtores (polimorfismo) então se você declarar sem parâmetros como `access` no exemplo, vai chamar o construtor sem parâmetros que supõe `n = 6` e `N = 1800`. Mas na declaração de `outro` vai criar a classe com `n=12` e `N = 3600`. Talvez ache mais cômodo assim.

E dentro dos construtores você pode gerar os vetores `Str` e `Dec` e depois dividir o código de `strbinars()` que manipula os vetores usando uma função para cada manipulação. Assim fica mais fácil de testar, provavelmente.

Não fui adiante com seu programa porque não postou a especificação e não entendo os algoritmos, então espero que essas observações ajudem em algo.

Não entendi essas declarações:

```
    char b1n[1] = { '1' };
    char b0n[1] = { '0' };
```

Que são vetores de um único `char` e que não são alterados nunca? Não podiam ser

```
        const char b1n = '1';
```

por exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

- > @arfneto

> "Essa construção sugere que strnbinars() é como um
> construtor da classe TransformStrsToDec."*

Eu pretendi fazer com que strnbinars() fosse o nome do método da classe TransformStrsToDec.
Eu coloquei muita coisa dentro desse método e talvez não deveria ter feito isso. Dentro desse método, os strings que estão dentro de storageRangeStr são transformados em decimal. Depois, dentro desse mesmo método, eu escolhi os dois primeiros valores que estão dentro do vetor dec_storageRangeStr[0] pra converter novamente em string.  A saída é Selec0[0] (como pode ser visto no resultado do programa, chamado de "cromossomo"). E é essa saída que eu gostaria de "usar" novamente na outra classe chamada por mim de  Segment_crss.
Eu estou estudando suas sugestões e especialmente aperfeiçoar meus conhecimentos sobre construtores.